# How to return NULL if any data element in a "GROUP BY" field is NULL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have multiple tasks grouped by "PR" and "Gate" that have start and completion dates.  I want the query to look for the earliest start date and the latest completion date.  If there are any NULLs in the completion date (meaning not all tasks are complete for that gate (group of tasks) then it should return NULL for completion date.

[image: data]

I've tried:

```
SELECT PR, Gate, MIN(T_Start) AS Start_Date, MAX(T_Complete) AS  
Completion_Date 
FROM qry_Tasks_Extended
GROUP BY PR, Gate;
```

This resulted in Completion_Date field with the latest existing date no matter if there are NULLs.

[image: Desired]

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `iif()` expression:

```
SELECT PR, Gate, MIN(T_Start) AS Start_Date,
       IIF(COUNT(*) = COUNT(T_COMPLETE), 
           MAX(T_Complete),
           NULL
          ) AS Completion_Date 
FROM qry_Tasks_Extended
GROUP BY PR, Gate;
```

In any other database, you would use the standard `case` expression (which MS Access does not support):

```
SELECT PR, Gate, MIN(T_Start) AS Start_Date,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(T_COMPLETE) THEN MAX(T_Complete)
        END) AS Completion_Date 
FROM qry_Tasks_Extended
GROUP BY PR, Gate;
```